# What are the "slight changes" Gounod made to Bach's The Well-Tempered Clavier when he wrote Ave Maria?

Tags: j-s-bach

The [Wikipedia page for Ave Maria (Bach/Gounod)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Maria_(Bach/Gounod)) says:

> The piece consists of a melody by the French Romantic composer Charles Gounod that he superimposed over an only **very slightly changed version** of the Prelude No. 1 in C major, BWV 846, from Book I of J.S. Bach's The Well-Tempered Clavier, published in 1722. (emphasis mine)

What are the slight changes between Gounod's Ave Maria
and Bach's Prelude No. 1 in C major?

Comment: As the answer points out, Gounod did not make the change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gounod based his *Ave Maria* on a version of Bach's Prelude in C where one bar had been added. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ave_Maria_(Bach/Gounod)#Composition), the bar had been added by Christian Friedrich Gottlieb Schwencke.

Here is the passage as Bach wrote it, as published in Bach-Gesellschaft Ausgabe, vol. 14, pp.1-5, by Breitkopf und Härtel in 1866, edited by Franz Kroll.

[image: the passage as Bach wrote it, without the spurious bar]

Here is the passage with the spurious bar added, as published by Schirmer in 1898, edited by Louis Oesterle.

[image: the passage with the spurious bar]